# Navigate to fragment with MaterialDrawer

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, navigation

I have created a new Android Studio project and I have inplemented a Navigation Drawer based on the Github project by ([Mike Penz](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer))

Everything is working great so far but my only issue is that Navigation between fragments is not working.

I want every Item in the **Drawer** to open a separate Fragment.

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.senseidev.isensei.activities;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.mikepenz.fontawesome_typeface_library.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.ProfileSettingDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IProfile;
import com.senseidev.isensei.R;
import com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.HomeFragment;
import com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.PhotosFragment;
import com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.ProductsFragment;
import com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.ProfileFragment;
import com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.ServicesFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PROFILE_SETTING = 1;
    private Toolbar mainToolbar;
    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;

    private IProfile profile_1;
    private IProfile profile_2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        profile_1 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Dev").withEmail("developer@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ip_user_bi_photo));
        profile_2 = new ProfileDrawerItem().withName("Isen").withEmail("isen@gmail.com").withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ip_user_bi_photo));

        // Create the AccountHeader
        buildHeader(false, savedInstanceState);

        //create the drawer and remember the `Drawer` result object
        result = new DrawerBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withAccountHeader(headerResult)
                .withToolbar(mainToolbar)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_profile)
                                .withSelectedIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_belize)).withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account_box).actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_services)
                                .withSelectedIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_belize)).withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_device_hub).actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_products)
                                .withSelectedIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_belize)).withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_shopping_cart).actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn"),

                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_images)
                                .withSelectedIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_belize)).withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_camera_roll).actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))
                                .withTag("Bullhorn")



                )
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                        // do something with the clicked item :D

                        selectDrawerItem((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier(), drawerItem);

                        return true;
                    }
                })
                .addStickyDrawerItems(
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_all_right_reserved).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_copyright).withEnabled(false)
                ).build();

    }


    /**
     * small helper method to reuse the logic to build the AccountHeader
     * this will be used to replace the header of the drawer with a compact/normal header
     *
     * @param compact
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    private void buildHeader(boolean compact, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.ip_menu_header_bg)
                .withCompactStyle(compact)
                .addProfiles(
                        profile_1,
                        profile_2,

                        new ProfileSettingDrawerItem()
                                .withName("Add Account")
                                .withDescription("Add new GitHub Account")
                                .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_add)
                                        .actionBar().paddingDp(5).colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text)).withIdentifier(PROFILE_SETTING),
                        new ProfileSettingDrawerItem().withName("Manage Account").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings)
                )
                .withOnAccountHeaderListener(new AccountHeader.OnAccountHeaderListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onProfileChanged(View view, IProfile profile, boolean current) {
                        //sample usage of the onProfileChanged listener
                        //if the clicked item has the identifier 1 add a new profile ;)
                        if (profile instanceof IDrawerItem && ((IDrawerItem) profile).getIdentifier() == PROFILE_SETTING) {
                            IProfile newProfile = new ProfileDrawerItem()
                                    .withNameShown(true)
                                    .withName("Kensei")
                                    .withEmail("kensei@gmail.com")
                                    .withIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ip_user_bi_photo));
                            if (headerResult.getProfiles() != null) {
                                //we know that there are 2 setting elements. set the new profile above them ;)
                                headerResult.addProfile(newProfile, headerResult.getProfiles().size() - 2);
                            } else {
                                headerResult.addProfiles(newProfile);
                            }
                        }

                        //false if you have not consumed the event and it should close the drawer
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(int ItemId, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch (ItemId) {

            case 1:
                fragmentClass = ProfileFragment.class;
                break;

            case 2:
                fragmentClass = ServicesFragment.class;
                break;

            case 3:
                fragmentClass = ProductsFragment.class;
                break;

            case 4:
                fragmentClass = PhotosFragment.class;
                break;

            default:
                fragmentClass = HomeFragment.class;
        }
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        result.closeDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        //add the values which need to be saved from the accountHeader to the bundle
        outState = headerResult.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.senseidev.isensei.activities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my HomeFragment.java

```
package com.project.app.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.project.app.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {


    public HomeFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       return view;
    }

}
```

This is my fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.senseidev.isensei.fragments.HomeFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="HOME" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your XLM activity layout should first has a framelayout slot for your fragments to be added and replaced on.

add this new method that will be responsible of creating and adding your fragments to the activity based on the item id selected from your drawer:

```
public void selectDrawerItem(int ItemId,IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
    // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch(ItemId) {
        case 1:
            fragmentClass = PageFragment2.class;
            break;
        case 2:
            fragmentClass = PageFragment2.class;
            break;
         default:
            fragmentClass = PageFragment2.class;
    }
    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    result.closeDrawer();
}
```

call this method from the withOnDrawerItemClickListener like this:

```
         .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem)
                {
                    // do something with the clicked item :D

                    selectDrawerItem((int)drawerItem.getIdentifier(), drawerItem);
                    return true;
                }
            })
```

this may not simulate requirements but will provide you with the logic, good luck.

add .withIdentifier()

```
.addDrawerItems(
                    new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_profile)
                            .withIdentifier(1)
                            .withSelectedIconColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.app_belize)).withIconTintingEnabled(true)
                            .withIcon(new IconicsDrawable(this, GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_account_box).actionBar().colorRes(R.color.material_drawer_dark_primary_text))
                            .withTag("Bullhorn"),
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - however I still need some help

I have added a Framelayout to the (activity_main.xml) but there is still an issue as it is NOT switching fragments

I have updated my code above

Comment: how did you know that fragment is not showing? this may not be obvious unless each fragment contains different things, like different background colors or the textview you added display different text, it is always showing HOME. Try setting different background color for the textview and showing different text and see what happens.

Comment: Each and every fragment has it's own layout.xml (Each with it's own TextView with diffirent TEXT) - But like you said,it is allways showing JUST "HOME"

There must be something wrong but I cannot figure out what

Comment: seems to me that switch statement is not passed an item identifier and always reach the default section. add an identifier to each item you configure like the example I added to my answer, believe this will solve the problem and fragments will replace. no need to say that identifier should be unique across items and the same in switch statement.